# Start row_number() depending on a specific value, and if there is no value then start in another way?

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I have the following table which has information of documents worked by employee, you can see that different employees can work with the same document throughout the day.
I need to get the start date/time when a employee started working on a document, but the thing is that sometimes they do no start working on a document until they click start on the system which is when the process_type gets the value 1, but I also need the information when other employees did not work on the document (do not have value on process_type).

Main table

[image: Main table]

The desired result would be as presented in this table (row = 1 being the start of the event)

Desired result

[image: Desired result]

I've tried using row_number, over with partition_by, even using WHERE clause or CASE WHEN, but it keeps giving row = 1 when the name changes to another employee...

Comment: can you show example data and expected ?
can you explain more(if process_type=0 then 1 how did you cauluate  other row row )?

Comment: The first six rows all have the same timestamp but two different employees. Is that a mistake? Is there an rule that would have all of John's rows being grouped ahead of Emma's?

Comment: Regarding the sample of data given above, there are different situations that can happen working with a document, as you can see on the table some employees have process_type = 1, this is because they did work on the document and that row indicates the date/time when they started working on it. Some employees do not have process = 1 and that means that the document was assigned to them but they did not work on it OR the document was assigned to them and they audited the document and that does not get registered as = 1. That's why I need to get the start of event of each employee

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text

Answer (score 0):

Standard gaps and islands approach to delineate into block where the counter resets. Assuming there's (at most) only one row with a process type of 1, in the second step we just need to grab that particular row number to calculate a relative offset for rows that will follow it. If no such value is present then the fallback will be to use the first row number within that block as the starting point for counting. The adjusted output row number then derives from these values:

```
with grouped as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (
            partition by document_id
            order by
                last_modification,
                case when process_type is null then 0 else 1 end,
                employee) as rn0,
        row_number() over (
            partition by document_id, employee
            order by
                last_modification,
                case when process_type is null then 0 else 1 end) as rn
    from T
), tagged as (
    select *,
        min(case when process_type = 1 then rn end) over (
            partition by document_id, employee, rn0 - rn) as ofs,
        min(rn) over (
            partition by document_id, employee, rn0 - rn) as ofs2
    from grouped
)
select document_id, employee, last_modification, process_type,
    case when rn <  ofs then 0
         when rn >= ofs then rn - ofs + 1
         else rn - ofs2 + 1 end as "row"
from tagged
order by document_id, rn0, employee;
```

Works fine for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/Ot9wfM0W

With the sample data above the first six rows all have the same timestamp. As listed, Emma's row comes last. (Perhaps that's just because the time has been truncated by minute?) If that's not a mistake then you'll need to define a rule to handle such scenarios. My rule was to sort by employee, which is essentially arbitrary. In my fiddle I've adjusted the time sequence to avoid the overlapping times.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and showing how it can be resolved!! I'll give it a try with my sample of data and modify it a bit, since as you have stated the time is truncated at minutes and it does not show seconds, and sometimes the same employee can comeback and work on the same document, It's interesting to say the least working with this kind of situations.